# How to match text to an array with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to match text to an array with a pause between each iteration. Is my if statement and array match incorrect?

```
var animals = ["turtle", "dolfin"];

setTimeout(function() {

  $("tr").each(function(){
    if($(this).$("td:eq(0)").text().inArray(animals)){
      $(this).$("button").hide();
    }
    else{
    }
  });

}, 5000);

<tr>
  <td>turtle></td>
  <td>lion</td>
  <td><button>correct</button></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>cat></td>
  <td>dog</td>
  <td><button>correct</button></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `$(this).$("td:eq(0)")` wut

Comment: I don't see anything in your question that would cause or attempt to cause a pause *between* iterations.

Comment: I wanted to only use the text in the first cell of each row.

Comment: @KevinB I'm with you on the `$(this).$("td:eq(0)")` in the if statement.  But the `setTimeout()` will cause a 5 second delay between iterations, provided the syntax errors are fixed.

Comment: @user9263373 the setTimeout will cause a 5 second delay before any iterations occur, then they'll all happen at once.

Comment: @KevinB I stand corrected.  You're right, other than the initial 5 second delay, no delay occurs between iterations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There are some issues with your code:**

**Your `tr` is not within a `table` tag.**

```
<tr>
^
```

**You're using the jQuery symbol in wrong places**

```
if($(this).$("td:eq(0)").text().inArray(animals)){
           ^

$(this).$("button").hide();
        ^
```

**You need to compare the returned value from `$.inArray()` as follow:**

```
$.inArray() > -1
```

**You have an empty `else`**

```
 else{
 }
 ^
```

**Look this code snippet with those fixes:**

```js
var animals = ["turtle", "dolfin"];

setTimeout(function() {
  $("tr").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).children("td:eq(0)").text();
    if ($.inArray(text, animals) > -1) {
      $("#" + text).hide();
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>turtle</td>
    <td>lion</td>
    <td><button id='turtle'>correct</button></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>cat</td>
    <td>dog</td>
    <td><button id='cat'>correct</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

See? now the code is working well with your logic.

Comment: excellent.  However one additional change is needed.  As @KevinB pointed out the `setTimeout()` needs to go inside the `$("tr").each()` loop to cause the delay between iterations.

Comment: @user9263373 Right, however like I said *the code is working well with your logic*, so, the OP should modify that :-)

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation.

Answer (score -2):

Your if statement should be like this:
    if($(this).find("td:eq(0)").text().inArray(animals) > -1){

Comment: why should it be like that?

Comment: because of what you said

Comment: I just deleted what I said

Comment: @KevinB - where?

Comment: `$(this).$` isn't a function.

Comment: ahh, so not a syntax error at all then :p it's an error in usage :p

Comment: I see what the problem is now.